# how to insert data to database with vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, routes, vue-router

i trying to create a crud system using vue js and laravel.

i already create api route and more...

but when i click submit i got message `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

here my `AddArtist.vue` file

```
<form @submit.prevent="add">
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="artist.name"  placeholder="Artist Name">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
        return {
            errors: [],
            image: '',
            artist: {
                    name: '',
                }
        }
        },
        methods: {
            add() {
                axios.post('/api/artist/store-artist', this.$data.artist)
                    .then((response) => {
                        alert('Success add Artist')
                        console.log(response)
                    })
            },
        },
            mounted() {
                console.log('Add Artist Mounted.')
            }
    }
</script>
```

and my `api.php` route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    Route::post('addartist/store-artist', 'ArtistController@store');
});
```

and here my controller `ArtistController.php`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        dd($input);
    }
```

and the last is my model `Artist.php`

```
class Artist extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'artist';
    protected $fillable = ['artist_name', 'date_birth', 'cover', 'gender'];
}
```

Comment: add csrf token in axios hrader

Comment: where is......?

Comment: @DhruvRaval `if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}` already set it in boostrap.js

Answer (score 0):

that is typo error:

change  `addartist/store-artist` to  `artist/store-artist` in route

Your api is :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    Route::post('addartist/store-artist', 'ArtistController@store');
});
```

and you are doing :

```
axios.post('/api/artist/store-artist', this.$data.artist)
                    .then((response) => {
                        alert('Success add Artist')
                        console.log(response)
                    })
```

Comment: still not working, i get `405 (Method Not Allowed)` and `Error: Request failed with status code 405`

Comment: possible solutions 1) remove middeware from this route  2) run `php artisan route:list` you will get all routes of your application check route url.

Comment: do you need to remove the `dd` from the store method?