# Error using FormRequest in Laravel 9 (The POST method is not supported for this route.)

Tags: laravel

I'm creating an API in Laravel 9, and I'm getting this error when using my FormRequest.

Edit:
I already tried with:
`php artisan route: clear`
and also
`php artisan route: cache`

`php artisan route:list`

```
  POST       _ignition/execute-solution ...... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController
  GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check .................. ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST       _ignition/update-config ............... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD   api/categories ......................................... generated::lHkZOL5tf3LIcEQ8 › CategoryController@index
  POST       api/sections ............................................ generated::UOlJ66qvitxlxVFJ › SectionController@store
  GET|HEAD   api/statuses ............................................. generated::QEy3vMPtQoyTF9ZF › StatusController@index
  POST       api/surveys .............................................. generated::ugYzFBQ10OqCe15t › SurveyController@store
  GET|HEAD   api/surveys .............................................. generated::cp4J8q5S2iAURPD9 › SurveyController@index
  GET|HEAD   api/user .......................................................................... generated::ZAKvw5kCNfZA65gG
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie ......................... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

My Route

```
Route::post('/sections', [SectionController::class, 'store']);
```

My Controller

```
class SectionController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreSectionRequest $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I use StoreSectionRequest it throws me the error:

`The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

But when I just use Request it works normally.

```
class SectionController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }
}
```

This is how it works correctly.

I don't understand what happens, because when creating my other routes I didn't have this problem.

```
class StoreSectionRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required | string ',
            'description' => 'nullable | string',
            'survey_id' => 'required | exists:surveys,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with code from StoreSectionRequest.

Comment: Try this once `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include the StoreSectionRequest, you are also including validation.

A validation error is beng thrown, but you have probably not indicated to Laravel that you need a json response and not a redirection to GET at the same route.

Make sure your API request includes `Accept: application/json` in the headers so that Laravel knows its a json request

Answer (score -1):

From the comment here: [how to insert data to database with vue and laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760122/how-to-insert-data-to-database-with-vue-and-laravel#comment94373752_53760699)

> Run php artisan route:list on console. You will get all routes of your
> appilcation. This is list of Route::post('/sections', [SectionController::class, 'store']); routes.By route list you will get idea of
> URI and Action

Comment: Yes, I already executed the command, and it appears
post /sections

Comment: You must include the link when copying content. You have been warned.